# Deploy azure arm template from local git

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I know you can push from local git and deploy code is azure web app.

But i want

first Deploy complete arm template from scratch using local git push.
and in the same push i want to deploy website code.

Now question is if arm template is creating web app from scratch then which git repo to push .

i am confused in this can some body tell me proper way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

well, you would need to create a hook, that would launch a script that would deploy your template. After the deployment is complete your script would get the git url from the webapp it deployed and push from local git to that repo.

That being said, it is 100 times easier to just place files on github and configure continuous delivery that would happen on its own. all you would need to do is to push to git from local repo.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-deploy-local-git
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-continuous-deployment